# Displaying last two months up to selected date in Direct Query mode

Tags: powerbi

I am working with a dataset in Power BI that contains sales data, updated weekly. Each record has a date and the number of sales. I've set up a stacked bar chart to display sales data for the last 2 months. However, I'm looking for a way to extend the history dynamically based on a slicer selection. Specifically, when selecting a date from half a year ago in the slicer, I want the chart to show data from the two months leading up to that selected date, making the selected date the last date shown in the chart.

I'm operating in Direct Query mode and cannot switch to Import mode due to the nature of the data and requirements of the project. Attempts to achieve this, including creating and linking a separate date table to the slicer, have resulted in the chart only displaying the singular selected date, without showing the preceding two months of data as intended.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to configure this in Power BI, particularly within the constraints of Direct Query mode? I'm looking for any advice or insight on how to display a dynamic range of dates in the chart based on slicer selection, while still adhering to Direct Query limitations.

Thanks in advance for any insights or advice!

[Example of the current Bar chart with only the selected date from the slicer in stead of an overview of the last 2 months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrNab.jpg)

What I've already tried:

1. Adding a Separate Date Table: I introduced a separate date table to my model, hoping to use it for slicer selections and thereby dynamically adjust the displayed date range in the chart. Expectation: By linking this table to my main data table, I anticipated that selecting a date in the slicer would show sales data from that date going back 2 months in the chart. Outcome: The chart ended up only displaying data for the singular date selected in the slicer, not the desired 2-month range leading up to it.
2. Adjusting Slicer Settings: Based on a suggestion, I tried modifying the slicer settings to allow selections of data from the current date going back by days, weeks, months, or years. Expectation: This seemed like it could offer a workaround by providing a dynamic date range for analysis. Outcome: While helpful, this approach defaulted to using the current date as the reference point, not aligning with my need to set the end date based on slicer selection and show the preceding 2 months of data up to that point.